# select the first, last, and single observations in a data set

Tags: r

Is there a way to keep the first and last observation by a group (id1 here), and also groups with single observations?

For example if I have:

```
   id1 id2
#1    1   1
#2    2   2
#3    2   3
#4    2   4
#5    2   5
#6    3   6
#7    3   7
#8    3   8
#9    4   9
#10   5  10
#11   5  11
#12   5  12
```

I would want:

```
  id1 id2
#1   1   1
#2   2   2
#3   2   5
#4   3   6
#5   3   8
#6   4   9
#7   5  10
#8   5  12
```

I've tried using dplyr group by id1 and then slicing for first and last rows but it duplicates my single observations.

For bonus points, I have another binary variable, in which I would only want to keep the first and last observations when this variable==1:

```
     id1 id2 binary
#1    1   1      1
#2    2   2      1
#3    2   3      1
#4    2   4      1
#5    2   5      1
#6    3   6      0
#7    3   7      0
#8    3   8      0
#9    4   9      1
#10   5  10      1
#11   5  11      1
#12   5  12      1
```

and I'd want:

```
     id1 id2 binary
#1    1   1      1
#2    2   2      1
#5    2   5      1
#6    3   6      0
#7    3   7      0
#8    3   8      0
#9    4   9      1
#10   5  10      1
#12   5  12      1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  id1 = c(1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5),
  id2 = 1:12,
  binary = c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
)

df %>%
  group_by(id1) %>%
  filter(
    # binary == 1, # uncomment this for bonus points :)
    row_number() == 1 | row_number() == n()
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

With `row_number()` I'm checking a group-wise ascending sequence to retain only those rows that are either the first (`row_number() == 1`), *or* the last element in the group (`row_number() == n()`, where `n()` gives you the number of observations in each group).

I believe there is more elegant or computationally efficient solutions, but this should at least do the trick.

Comment: Just like we often request minimal working examples in the questions (including and specifically only the necessary packages), I suggest we should hold the same standard in answers we give. As such, please change your required packages from the large meta-package to just what is necessary (`dplyr` in this case).

Comment: Vielen dank hans :)

Comment: `1:n()` is really just `row_number()` (which is clearer exactly what you want/need ... *declarative*).

Comment: yeah, that wouldn't have covered my initial solution, but I agree, it's more straightforward just using `row_number()` and comparing for either `1` or `n()`.
edited my response accordingly

Answer (score 1):

This should be simple. Using @hansjaneinvielleicht's data:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(id1) %>%
  slice(unique(c(1, n())))

# # A tibble: 8 x 3
# # Groups:   id1 [5]
#     id1   id2 binary
#   <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
# 1     1     1      1
# 2     2     2      1
# 3     2     5      1
# 4     3     6      0
# 5     3     8      0
# 6     4     9      1
# 7     5    10      1
# 8     5    12      1
```

---

For the extra credit retention of binary 0:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(id1, binary) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% c(1L, n()) | binary < 1)
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
# # Groups:   id1, binary [5]
#     id1   id2 binary
#   <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
# 1     1     1      1
# 2     2     2      1
# 3     2     5      1
# 4     3     6      0
# 5     3     7      0
# 6     3     8      0
# 7     4     9      1
# 8     5    10      1
# 9     5    12      1
```

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to leave id1=3 in this case untouched (as binary==0)?
So instead would want to keep all the three observations in id1==3